# google spreadsheet update cells causing server error 502 when using google-drive-ruby gem v1.0.5

Tags: ruby, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I update a google worksheet from a workbook using the google_drive gem.
I get the worksheet object using the below code

```
ws=session.spreadsheet_by_key(doc_key).worksheet_by_title(spend_sheet_name)
```

After changing contents of cells inside worksheet, I try to save the worksheet like so:

```
ws.save
```

I get this error while executing the `ws.save` command

```
    Response code 502 for post https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/yyyyyyyyy/private/full/batch: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 502 (Server Error)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>502.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

I tried following the instructions and setup a begin rescue block which retries `ws.save` after 30 seconds but I still get the same error.

Update: 
this works when updating small cells ~3 to 5. But when I try to update >(300 rows X 13 columns) I get the above error.
I am using https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby version 1.0.5
I also tried updating the gem to v2.0.1 but I get the same error

Can someone help me out here please.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/gnHYYDd1lhw/FDmJvyhFCp8J),  it seems that there are some problems with Drive/Docs services that's why you got **server error 502**. Try clearing your cache and cookies resolve. You can quickly clear your cache by refreshing your browser while holding the Shift key.

Also from this [thread](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2992016?hl=en), if you're seeing a "Temporary Error (502)" message or other server error message when you try to access Google Docs, Sheets, or Slides, it means that your documents are temporarily unavailable. These errors generally resolve themselves within a few minutes, so please wait a bit before trying to access them again.

Comment: I cannot clear my cache or cookies because I am not accessing google sheet via browser. I use https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby gem.
Also I am facing this problem not temporarily. this is happening everytime since the last two weeks